# how to resolve stack shape inconsistent in java?

Tags: java, exception, jar

I have same jar (same version & same size too) at compile and run time, and I
have compiled the java batch code with jdom-1.1.jar for XML creation,when I execute my java batch its throwing below exception while reach the respective class which has Jdom import statement and respetive jdom codes. please help

```
java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY012 stack shape inconsistent; class=com/xxx/yyy/handler, method=xmlWritter(Ljava/util/Map;)V, pc=90
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:72)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:
```